Is there a process/utility to get uuid mismatches fixed up?
I use dd to make byte-for-byte copies which are both my backup and and are immediatly bootable in backup system. However later routine ubuntu updates grumble that uuid's are out-of-whack: "no such disk can be found." I worry that sometime, somehow, the grumble will have predicted an unmanageable problem. Is there a corrective utility/process/procedure that can update the uuid situation? (Inputting uuid's by hand is just an error waiting to happen.)
